# Configuring SQL Server database c# with Windows form application

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a Windows form application and I wish to configure my database on localhost that is running on SQL Server 2008 so that when my application is running from other people's computer, other people will have the ability to access my database to get the information there.

It is because I am the only one who can access the database on my own computer.

Currently I am using this code in my db to connect to my localhost database.

Code:

```
SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection("Server = localhost; Initial Catalog= dbName; Trusted_Connection = True");
```

I have heard that you can config your code through the `app.config` using `connectionstring` which I am not sure if this event work, if it does, I have no idea how to do that and use that `connectionString` from my code. Help and code for reference will be appreciated

Comment: Your database would have to be visible to the other person.  If they are not on your local network, that means opening up your firewall to allow access to your database.  That's quite a security hazard and needs a great deal of expertise to do without gaping security holes.

Comment: @EricJ. I am wondering if there is a way to do this? It doesn't make any sense if I am the only one who can access my database. Then how can other user use my application if they aren't allow to access my db?

Comment: The most common pattern these days is to provide a web service that runs on your computer, and have the program you are writing make a call to that web service for each action involving the database.  This provides an additional layer of isolation between potential hackers and your data.  You **can** expose your data (in which case change the `localhost` part to your IP address or DNS name of your computer, and open appropriate ports on your firewall).  It's just risky.  If you go this route, try to open your firewall only to *their* IP.

Comment: What other people are you talking about exactly?  Do you mean other workers in your office?  Other family members in your home?  Any user of your app anywhere in the world?  As suggested, there are security issues to consider but they become less of an issue if you're talking about a small group of trusted users on the same network as opposed to strangers on the internet.

Comment: it is a small group of user. Let say in the office for internal use

Comment: If it's a small group of trusted users on the same network then you can simply configure SQL Server to allow remote connections if it isn't already and then open the appropriate ports in your firewall.  You may also need to update security on your instance to specify access is allowed for a particular group.  You would then use the machine name in the connection string.